# Why are identical words pronounced differently at certain locations of the Shema?

Tags: pronunciation, shema

Why are identical words pronounced differently at certain locations of the Shema? Or is this only for Sefardim?  The two identical phrases in question are in the Veahávta and then again in the Vehayá:

1. "**beshivtéja beveitéja uvlejtéja vadérej, uvshojbéja uvkuméja**."
   (Please note the change of accent mark between both readings)
2. "**beshivtejá beveitéja, uvlejtejá vadérej uvshojbejá uvkuméja**.
   (The J should be read as CH for Ashkenazim)

Keep in mind that I'm not referring to differences between Sefardim vs Ashkenazim pronunciation, but within the Shema itself.  I will assume that this pronunciation may apply to Ashkenazim as well and that the issue may be one of Hebrew grammar. But what exactly is that rule (if it is one of grammar)?

The example above was taken from the Sidur Tefilát Binyamin by Benjamin Senker

Comment: This seems to be a mispronunciation. The correct way for both paragraphs is the way you list second. That said, I don't know *why* it's mispronounced, which is what you ask, so I'm not posting this as an answer. Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. I recommend [a brief intro to the site](http://mi.yodeya.com/tour); you may also wish to [change your username](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/edit/4937) (unless you're fond of the number 4937).

Comment: Can you clarify where you have seen/heard the first method of pronunciation (which AFAICT is inaccurate)?

Comment: The example above was taken from the Sidur Tefilát Binyamin by Benjamin Senker. This sidur is in Hebrew and Spanish using the Ashkenazí custom.

Comment: Based on all of my Tanakh's and my extensive Siddur collection of various nushaot, there is no question that msh210 is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 5):

The two passages are from [Deuteronomy 6:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.7?lang=bi) and [11:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.19?lang=bi), respectively:

1. וְשִׁנַּנְתָּ֣ם לְבָנֶ֔יךָ וְדִבַּרְתָּ֖ בָּ֑ם בְּשִׁבְתְּךָ֤ בְּבֵיתֶ֙ךָ֙ וּבְלֶכְתְּךָ֣ בַדֶּ֔רֶךְ וּֽבְשָׁכְבְּךָ֖ וּבְקוּמֶֽךָ׃
2. וְלִמַּדְתֶּ֥ם אֹתָ֛ם אֶת־בְּנֵיכֶ֖ם לְדַבֵּ֣ר בָּ֑ם בְּשִׁבְתְּךָ֤ בְּבֵיתֶ֙ךָ֙ וּבְלֶכְתְּךָ֣ בַדֶּ֔רֶךְ וּֽבְשָׁכְבְּךָ֖ וּבְקוּמֶֽךָ׃

Note that both the vowels and the cantillation marks - which denote accentation - on these words are identical in the Torah. I've never heard of any dispute in tradition about either of these elements of these verses. The accent marks in your transliteration of (1) are incorrect and should be corrected to match those of (2).